# How to make \NewDocumentCommand respect spaces and paragraphs?

Tags: macros, latex3

Given the following macro defintion

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { titlepage }
{
    title  .tl_set:N  = \l__titlepage_title_tl,
    name  .tl_set:N  = \l__titlepage_name_tl,
    place  .tl_set:N  = \l__titlepage_place_tl,
    date .tl_set:N  = \l__titlepage_date_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \myTest } { +m }
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { titlepage } { #1 }
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \begin{center}
            {
                \fontsize{20}{20}
                \selectfont
                Some Text Here % Why are spaces ignored?

                % Why is no new paragraph created here? 

                And More Text\\ With Spaces
            }

            \textbf{\l__titlepage_title_tl}

            \l__titlepage_name_tl
        \end{center}

    \end{titlepage}
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Calling it like this:

```latex
\myTest{title=My Big Fat Title, name=John Doe}
```

I yield

[image: All stuff stacked together]

How can I make this macro behave as if in "normal" LaTeX mode?

Comment: you are explicitly opting in to "ignore space" mode with `\ExplSyntaxOn`  use `~` to get a space. (and `\par` to get a paragraph break)

Comment: No chance to say `\ExplSyntaxOff` **within** the macro?

Comment: no , like `\makeatletter` you need to do it outside the macro, really typing `~` isn't harder than typing a space, you soon get used to it.

Comment: Well there's always the option of writing some wrapper script to do regex-replace like replacing `"..."` with ⟨content inside replace space with `~`⟩, whether it's worth it is up to you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces and endlines have always been a problem in TeX programming. When starting to develop a new programming style for LaTeX, namely `expl3`, the team decided to

1. provide tools for controlling expansion without the need of guessing where to place possibly long strings of `\expandafter`;
2. provide tools for avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel each time a particular problem arises;
3. remove altogether the problem of spaces and endlines.

<sub>Somebody would say I made my rep here by answering questions about unexpected spaces creeping in.</sub>

However, this comes at a price: in some cases spaces are needed in the code, if something to be typeset is present.

For such cases the provided solution is to use `~` that, in the scope of `\ExplSyntaxOn` is a single space token; consecutive `~` tokens obey the standard rule for spaces, so they're compressed to a single space; moreover, `~` is *not* removed at the end of lines, differently from spaces in the standard setting. Conversely `~` is removed at the beginning of lines, because of TeX rules.

```
        \begin{center}
            {
                \fontsize{20}{32}\selectfont
                Some~Text~Here\\
                And~More~Text\\ With~Spaces\\
            }
            \textbf{\l__titlepage_title_tl}\\
            \l__titlepage_name_tl
        \end{center}
```

I changed `\fontsize{20}{20}` into `\fontsize{20}{32}`: otherwise lines would be very compressed.

Instead of the ignored blank lines I used `\\` when inside `center` (which does `\par`, but also other jobs). Outside of `center`, use `\par`.